# Where are Safari 6.0 passwords saved?

Tags: safari, macos, security, keychain

Prior to version 6.0 Safari had no features for managing passwords distinct from the system wide support provided by Keychain:

[image: Before Safari 6.0]

but Safari 6.0 adds a new tab in its Preferences dialog for saving and managing passwords for websites:

[image: After Safari 6.0]

Does this change correspond to a change in locations for storing or rules for managing the security of passwords? Are Safari passwords still stored securely in the Keychain or are they in a new, separate store?

Where are Safari 6.0 passwords saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The passwords are still saved in the Keychain, and not a separate 'new' location. Safari 6 just includes a new front end for accessing them directly without having to go to the Keychain Access application.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. To append to my answer, in case you have an issue with the new Passwords pane in Safari, you can still manage (delete/etc) them in Keychain Access.